# Override Rails updated_at attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timestamp, overriding, attributes

I would like to modify **updated_at** attribute so that every time record is updated it would only show date and hours while hours and minutes being zeros. **Instead of 2010-08-13 11:04:12, there would be 2010-08-13 11:00:00**. What is the most rational way to do this in Rails 2.3?

## Update

The reason why I want to do what I have asked is because I would like to sort data, by date with hours and seconds omitted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to change the value stored in the database; change how you are outputting it:

```
timestamp = @model.updated_at # where @model is your model object

# output it in a format that overrides the values for minute and second
puts timestamp.strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
```

See the [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298) ruby doc for other format specifiers you can use.

---

Based on your update, I would still not change how `updated_at` is stored, but instead format the date within the `ORDER BY` of your query. For instance, you could

```
ORDER BY DATE(updated_at), HOUR(updated_at), ...
```

I did a very quick profiling test on a live table in my application, which has about 22,000 records. `ORDER BY updated_at` took between 2.94 and 3.19s to complete, with a mean time of 3.00s. `ORDER BY DATE(updated_at), HOUR(updated_at)` took between 2.93 and 3.06s to complete, with a mean time of 2.99s. Here's the profiling data:

```
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                                                           |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 2.94530500 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY updated_at                         |
|        2 | 2.94583800 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY updated_at                         |
|        3 | 3.18711700 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY updated_at                         |
|        4 | 2.96923700 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY updated_at                         |
|        5 | 2.97255400 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY updated_at                         |
|        6 | 3.06706800 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY DATE(updated_at), HOUR(updated_at) |
|        7 | 3.00414400 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY DATE(updated_at), HOUR(updated_at) |
|        8 | 2.95551500 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY DATE(updated_at), HOUR(updated_at) |
|        9 | 3.02181900 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY DATE(updated_at), HOUR(updated_at) |
|       10 | 2.93130000 | SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY DATE(updated_at), HOUR(updated_at) |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I haven't mentioned it, but the reason why I want to do what I have asked is because I would like to sort data, by date with hours and seconds omitted. Of course I could format date in my select, but I don't think it would be a good performance decision.

Comment: but what about performance, when using sql functions when querying data? Because that data will be really frequently queried, while very less frequently updated

Comment: You're going to have to go through a bit of a runaround to change how `updated_at` is stored because even if you try to set it manually, Rails will automatically set the value to what it wants when it goes to save the record.

Answer (score 1):

It's a time stamp object so your probably best off just to use a helper function to truncate the min/sec info.

Answer (score 1):

`whatever.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Daniel's solution.  However, if you're *100% positive* that you want to save the record with your modified "updated_at" field, you'll have to re-implement rails' auto-timestamping for the given model.

So, in your model, you can do the following:

```
self.record_timestamps = false # disables rails' auto-timestamping
before_create :set_created_at
before_save :set_updated_at  

def set_created_at
  self.created_at = Time.now
end
def set_updated_at
  self.updated_at = Time.now.change({:min => 0, :sec => 0}) # clears minutes and seconds
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you should do with active record. It's something that a view helper could accomplish and you don't need to alter the way things are getting saved which will probably just be more work in the future.

Think about `strftime` and how you can alter that instead.

In a helper file:

```
def format_date_for_rounded_hour(date)
    date.striftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:00")
end
```